# Twitter API returning list of followers larger than 70,000

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Using TwitterOAuth I'm trying to get the list of followers of an account with a large amount of followers. Since the API returns no more than 5,000 users per request, following the advice of other answers here and I tried to use cursors, but now I'm facing the problem than I can make only 15 requests per window so I can only get the last 70,000 followers . I thought about saving the cursor and making calls 15 minutes later, but the API returns the most recent follower first, so the saved cursor becomes inaccurate . What can I do to return follower lists larger than 70,000 ?

Comment: Can't you just save the results into a database and insert or update its content every 15 min.?

Comment: If you only need the number of followers (rather than the followers themselves) you could as well user the field `followers_count` with the command [GET users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show)